# How to add a tail element at end of the list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

When I try to use this statement : `tail->prev = newElement`;
then entire program just shuts down. I really wonder why.

```
struct LinkedList{
    string var_name;
    string scope_name;
    int scope; // 0 = global, 1 = public, 2 = private, 3 = ?
    LinkedList* next = NULL;
    LinkedList* prev = NULL;
};

struct LinkedList*  head;
struct LinkedList*  tail;  //I made this two global

void insert(LinkedList* &head, LinkedList* &newElement, LinkedList* &tail){
    newElement->next =NULL;

    if(!head){
        head = newElement;
        return;
    }
    else{
        LinkedList* last = head;
        while(last->next != NULL){
            last=last->next;
        }
        last->next = newElement;
        newElement->prev = last;
        tail = newElement; 
        tail = newElement->next;
        tail->prev = newElement;
    }
}

void LexicalAnalyzer:: var_list(){
    LinkedList* new_node = new LinkedList[sizeof(LinkedList)];
    GetToken();
    new_node->var_name = tmp.lexeme;
    new_node->scope_name = currentScope;
    if(currentScope == "global")
        new_node->scope = 0;
    else if(pubOrPri == 1)
        new_node->scope = 1;
    else if(pubOrPri == 2)
        new_node->scope = 2;
    insert(head, new_node, tail);
    //tail->prev = new_node;
    display();
    if(tmp.token_type == ID){
        GetToken();
        if(tmp.token_type == COMMA)
            var_list();
        else if(tmp.token_type == SEMICOLON){
            return;
        }
        else
            syntaxError();
    }
    else
        syntaxError();
}
```

The output gave me

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 3.269 s.

But if I delete `tail-> newElement;` and take away the parameter tail in the function. Everything's fine.

And I thought, tail is global then why wouldn't I just directly try           `tail->prev = new_Node;` in the `var_list()` function, didn't work as well.

Comment: Is `tail` a valid pointer at the time when you call insert?

Comment: `LinkedList* new_node = new LinkedList[sizeof(LinkedList)];` gives you a pointer to an array of `sizeof(LinkedList)` number of elements of `LinkedList`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You changed the code in your question after getting an answer? That's a recipe for confusion. Try sticking to one question per question. If you found out what is wrong with the initial code, then start a new question for the new code. If you did not find out what is wrong with the initial code, stick to it until you do.

Comment: If you have added a `tail` pointer, you do not need to iterate over the list to insert the new node at the end. `newElement->prev = tail; tail->next = newElement; tail = newElement;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any logic to deal with the initial state of `tail`, which is `nullptr`.

Change

```
if(!head){
    head = newElement;
    return;
}
```

to

```
if(!head){
    head = tail = newElement;
    return;
}
```

In addition, the line

```
    tail->prev = newElement;
```

needs to be

```
    tail = newElement;
```

in the `else` block.

**Disclaimer** I haven't tested whether the suggestion fixes the problem.

Comment: I have tried like this before:  last->next = newElement;
        newElement->prev = last;
        tail = newElement->next;
        tail->prev = newElement; but didn't work. and I just tired your way, didn't work as well...

Comment: @zichangwang, when you tried that, did you get the same error or a different error?

Comment: @R Sahu The same error, I don't know why the system is telling me I throw a garbage pointer. Feeling sad :(

Comment: ...I did your updated asnwer, still didn't work :(. I think may be I should try to rewrite my insertion function that to use insert in middle method. Since I have two initial nodes.

Comment: @zichangwang, please post a [mcve]. That will be helpful in tracking down the problem.

Comment: These are the only two functions that are associated with LinkedList in my program so far. Appreciate you anyway : )

Answer (score 0):

try this logic,

```
void insert(LinkedList* &head, LinkedList* &newElement, LinkedList* &tail){
        newElement->next =NULL;

        if(!head){
                head = tail = newElement; // your first node is both head and tail;
                return;
        }
        else{
                LinkedList* last = head;
                while(last->next != NULL){
                        last=last->next;
                }
                last->next = newElement;
                newElement->prev = last; // newElement is inserted to end of the list
                tail = newElement; // tail is moved to last element in the list
                //tail = newElement->next;
                newElement->next = NULL; // tail of next is always NULL; end of the list
                //tail->prev = newElement;
                tail->prev = last; // tail of prev must be last 
        }
}
```